# How to prevent duplicate upload in Excel to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to work with uploading excel in asp.net c# web form and save in sql however it also upload duplicate data in row.

Code
https://dotnetfiddle.net/nYKGpr

```cs
private bool uploadfile1()
{
    try
    {
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "" || FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "File Template")
        {
            this.checkDirectory();
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("") + "\\Uploads\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
            filename = FileUpload1.FileName;
            path = Server.MapPath("") + "\\Uploads\\";
            ExcelCS xl = new ExcelCS();
            xl.UserId = (Session["userid"] != null) ? Session["userid"].ToString() : String.Empty;
            xl.Session = (Session["sessionID"] != null) ? Session["sessionID"].ToString() : String.Empty;
            if (xl.ParseExcelFile(path + filename, true, 1))
            {
                listdata save = new listdata();
                if (save.save())
                {
                    Class.JSclass.ShowAlert(save.RecordsUploaded.ToString() + " item(s) uploaded and " + save.TotalUpdated.ToString() + " item(s) updated out of " + save.TotalRecords.ToString() + " Record(s).");
                    listweb.Class.Logger.writeLog(Session["userid"].ToString(), Session["sessionID"].ToString(), "frmUploadFile.uploadfile1", "File uploaded successfully!", "", "", Class.LogCategories.SELECT);
                    Class.JSclass.refreshMainPage();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Class.JSclass.ShowAlert("Invalid file format please use specified template.");
                listweb.Class.Logger.writeLog(Session["userid"].ToString(), Session["sessionID"].ToString(), "frmUploadFile.uploadfile1.ParseExcelFile", "Error: " + xl.Message, "", "", Class.LogCategories.SELECT);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Class.JSclass.ShowAlert("Error: " + e.Message);
        listweb.Class.Logger.writeLog(Session["userid"].ToString(), Session["sessionID"].ToString(), "frmUploadFile.uploadfile1", "Error: " + e.Message, "", "", Class.LogCategories.SELECT);
    }

    Class.JSclass.ShowAlert("File upload failed!");
    return false;
}
```

I tried only tried to save the upload in sql however with duplicate/ same data in upload/save in sql. I wanted to void the duplication of the data

Comment: You have 2 choices here. Either check if file already exists, and then reject, or in fact test for the file, and add a -1, then -2, then -3 etc. until you find a file without that name. So, if your files is myitems.xlsx, then if that exists, you use myitems-1.xlsx, and so on. So, what is supposed to occur if two users up-load the same file name? So, either test if the file exists, or run a loop appending -1, -2 etc. to file name until such time you find the file does not exist, and use that new file name.

Comment: Hi @AlbertD.Kallal, thank you for your feedback, however the system never intent to rename the file however is to scan the row of excel file if the field has duplicate entries or not save to sql.